# Orbeon Forms on Windows IIS 7 web server?

Tags: iis-7, orbeon

I am trying to evaluate Orbeon Forms, and want to install it on my personal laptop. I don't have a web server available to me, but I understand that Windows 7 comes with one, IIS (formerly Personal Web Server). But the Orbeon installation instructions say nothing about IIS (unless it's under a different name). Before I spend the time to figure out how to make IIS work, I'd like some assurance that Orbeon Forms will work under it. Can anyone tell me that?

Thanks!

Earl Morton

Answer (score 1):

Orbeon Forms runs within a [Java Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) container. Therefore it won't work directly under IIS, which is not a Java Servlet container.

You don't say in your question whether you *need* to use IIS, or whether you are open to using something else. If you absolutely need plain IIS, you are out of luck since, as mentioned above, IIS is not itself a Servlet container.

Now if you have the option to install something else, the good news is that it's really easy to [download and install Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi). Then follow the [Orbeon Forms installation instructions](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing) and you will be all set in a breeze.

Tomcat running on a laptop is what the Orbeon Forms developers (including myself) themselves use.

Then later you can explore whether you want to use IIS as a front-end for Tomcat, for example with the [IIS connector for Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html).

Comment: Thanks! I do not need IIS specifically--it was just available. I have installed Tomcat, and have Orbeon Forms working under it.